# Class and object error, undefined reference, string has no member named

Tags: c++, undefined-reference, stdstring

Hy, I try to learn to use classes and objects in c++, I made this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class plant

{
    public:
        plant();

    void setWater(int vz)
    {
        water = vz;
    }

    void setFood(int tp)
    {
        food = tp;
    }

    int getWater()
    {
        return water;
    }

    int getFood()
    {
        return food;
    }

private:
int water, food;
};

void plantCreate(string name[])
{
    for(int i=0;i<sizeof(name);++i)
    {
        plant name[i];  // undefined reference to `plant::plant()' 
        name[i].setWater(rand()%20);
        name[i].setFood(rand()%20);
    }
}

void plantPrint(string name[])
{
    for(int i=0;i<sizeof(name);++i)
    {
        cout << name[i] << ": Water= " << name[i].getWater() << ", Food= " << name[i].getFood() << endl;
        //error: ‘std::string’ has no member named ‘getWater’/'getFood'
    }
}

int main()
{
    string plantNames[5]={"Liliom", "Tulipan", "Narcisz", "Rozsa", "Pipacs"};
    plantCreate(plantNames);
    plantPrint(plantNames);
}
```

I get those two errors, first the string member, than the undefined reference if I comment out the `cout` from the `plantPrint` I get the second error. I tired to create the default constructor with `plant();` but it'sc just not working correctly. Any ideas? (I'm using a codeBlocks on Ubuntu)

Comment: You're trying to call the methods such as getWater() on a string, not an instance of a plant. Strings don't have this method. plantPrint's only parameter is a list of strings, so when you're iterating over that you're getting a string and not a plant.

Comment: Your default constructor is not working because you've only provided a declaration, not a definition. You need a function body (curly braces).

Comment: @FCo: No, the _syntax_ is perfectly fine. That's evidenced as you get a _linker_ error.

Comment: @Lago: Explain what you're trying to do. We cannot determine that from code which _doesn't_ accurately represent that goal!

Comment: Mainly I would like to store Plants (names, water level and food level), I try to create simulator which has a random weather, that inflicts the sunny and rainy days, and I can determine if the plant is dead (food < 0 && water < 0) or it is over watered (water > max) or it is ready to multiple (food == x && water == x). It will be two after that, and I can count the days when it reaches a specific amount of each plants. The inputs will be names and days only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second error `//error: ‘std::string’ has no member named ‘getWater’/'getFood'`:

You are tryng to call getWater and getFood on a string, in facts, your `name` variable is an array of string, and I think you want an array of plant.

**Edit**:
A correct PlantCreate function:

```
plantCreate(plant[] plantlist, string name[], int length)
{
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        planlist[i].setName(name[i]);  
        planlist[i].setWater(rand()%20);
        planlist[i].setFood(rand()%20);
    }
    return results;
}
```

Like that plantCreate will set your array of multiple plant instances.

Now a compatible plantPrint function with our plantCreate function:

```
  void plantPrint(plant[] plantlist, int length)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<length;++i)
        {
            cout << plantlist[i].getName() << ": Water= " << plantlist[i].getWater() << ", Food= " << plantlist[i].getFood() << endl;
        }
    }
```

And finally a compatible main with our functions:

```
int main()
{
    string plantNames[5]={"Liliom", "Tulipan", "Narcisz", "Rozsa", "Pipacs"};
    plant plantList[5];
    plantCreate(plantList, plantNames, 5);
    plantPrint(plantList,5);
}
```

Like that this might work. But sinces my c++ is a bit rusted, there can be some errors but you will be able to correct them. Also, maybe you should re-learn how instancation works, how types and variables work etc... :)

Moreover be careful when you use sizeof on an array, I dont think it returns the length of the array.

Comment: If I'm correct, the class members (each plant has it's own water and food object) should store the values, so I do not need a water and food arrays to sore them. If I use an array, I do not need the class, i can do a multi dim array, and It's done, but I would like to learn the classes. plantCreate should create each object, but it doesn't, what do you suggest?

Comment: @Lago First of all, apply what JaNL said. Like that you will have a correct  constructor. After that, correct your plateCreate function. Since c++ is strongly  and not dynamically tiped, you cant instanciate a plant objet in a variable of type string. So change your function like I in my answer (i will edit it). After that, you will get an array of plant by calling plantCreate. Change your function like i did and pass that array to printplant function.

Comment: @Lago Sorry Not what JaNL said but what steiner said, so create a valid empty constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Well obviously you have to describe what the constructor has to do. If you want him to do nothing just put :

```
plant() {}
```

But I would suggest at least :

```
plant() : water(0), food(0) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want use oo design, why dont you make your plantCreate and plantPrint to the Plant method? Also the plantCreate could just become a part of your constructor not a separate method. Remember to use pointer/reference for objects. Try this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Plant
{
    private:
        string name;
        int water, food;

    public:
        Plant(string name) : name(name)
        {
            plantCreate();
        }

        void setWater(int vz)
        {
            water = vz;
        }

        void setFood(int tp)
        {
            food = tp;
        }

        int getWater()
        {
            return water;
        }

        int getFood()
        {
            return food;
        }


        void plantCreate()
        {
            setWater(rand()%20);
            setFood(rand()%20);
        }
        void plantPrint()
        {
            cout << name << ": Water= " << getWater() << ", Food= " << getFood() << endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    string plantNames[5]={"Liliom", "Tulipan", "Narcisz", "Rozsa", "Pipacs"};
    Plant ** myPlants;
    myPlants = new Plant * [5];

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        myPlants[i] = new Plant(plantNames[i]);
        myPlants[i]->plantPrint();
    }
}
```